# How do I programmatically add EditTextPreferences to my PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, preferencescreen, edittextpreference

I am new to Android, so I need a little guidance on how to **programmatically** add **EditTextPreference** objects to my **PreferenceFragment**.

I am pulling in a list of values from a web service. I have saved them successfully to my **SharedPreferences**, and I use them to generate URLs (path portion).

I would like the users of my app to be able to edit these values, but after lots of searching on Google, it isn't clear to me how to **programmatically** add **EditTextPreference** objects to my **PreferenceFragment**.

Please note, my **PreferenceFragment** is working fine for the **SharedPreferences** values I hard code as names into the preference xml file (**PreferenceScreen**). I also know how to get my **SharedPreferences**, so don't worry about having to explain that portion to me.

I use **addPreferencesFromResource** in **onCreate** of my **PreferenceFragment**. Should I add them in the **onCreateView**? I was thinking I could get the **PreferenceCategory** and add them there? But again, I am not sure how to do that. I would really be grateful for the help!

// Code

```
PrefsFragment.java:
package com.example.lorddoineedhelp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); 
    // I am guessing I need to do something here?
    return v;
  }
}
```

XML File for PreferenceFragment:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Hard coded values -->
  <PreferenceCategory
          android:title="General">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="debug"
            android:title="Debug"
            android:summary="Enable Debug" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Address">
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:key="ipAddress"
        android:title="IP Address"
        android:summary="IP Address used for Image pings"
    />
    <EditTextPreference
          android:key="port"
          android:title="Port"
          android:summary="Port used for Image pings" />
  </PreferenceCategory>

  <!-- Where I want to add the values from my web service -->

   <PreferenceCategory 
       android:title="Paths"
       android:key="urlPaths">
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can add preferences, e.g. EditTextPreference, CheckBox, etc, programmatically in the "onCreate" method of the PreferenceFragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load "dummy" (empty) preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_channelconfig);

    PreferenceScreen screen = this.getPreferenceScreen(); // "null". See onViewCreated.

    // Create the Preferences Manually - so that the key can be set programatically.
    PreferenceCategory category = new PreferenceCategory(screen.getContext());
    category.setTitle("Channel Configuration");
    screen.addPreference(category);

    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(screen.getContext());
    checkBoxPref.setKey(channelConfig.getName() + "_ENABLED");
    checkBoxPref.setTitle(channelConfig.getShortname() + "Enabled");
    checkBoxPref.setSummary(channelConfig.getDescription());
    checkBoxPref.setChecked(channelConfig.isEnabled());

    category.addPreference(checkBoxPref);
}
```

The crucial step is the `addPreferencesFromResource(...)`, with a dummy xml to attach an empty PreferenceScreen to the fragment. Without this, there is no "top-level Preference that is the root of a Preference hierarchy", thus `this.getPreferenceScreen()` returns Null.

The XML I used was just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orderingFromXml="true">

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This works well for xml-less preferences. There's actually no need for dummy XML, this can be used instead:

    PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getActivity());
    setPreferenceScreen(screen);

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to create a PreferenceFragment programmatically:

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getActivity());
        setPreferenceScreen(screen);

        EditTextPreference preference = new EditTextPreference(screen.getContext());
        preference.setKey("EditTextPreference");
        preference.setTitle("Edit Text Preference");
        preference.setSummary("Click the preference to edit text.");
        screen.addPreference(preference);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works in the **onCreateView** method but it does in the **onViewCreated**.
Here is my code (Inside a subclass of PreferenceFragment):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    this.getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(new EditTextPreference(getActivity()));
}
```