# Android adding form fields to a preferencefragment dynamically without xml

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity, preferencefragment

Can't seem to find any non-deprecated (HONEYCOMB+) examples showing how to add dynamically created preferences to a `preferencefragment` instead of using an `xml` resource that predefined the form fields.

Specifically I'm trying to create a list of check-boxes with Bluetooth devices that have been paired with the phone.  Using `mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()` and presumably the `CheckBoxPreference`.

```
class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private Context context = getBaseContext();
    private int i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //get Bluetooth Adapter
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("bt_devices", 0);
            this.i = 0;

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(context);
                checkBoxPreference.setKey("btDevice_"+this.i);
                checkBoxPreference.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("btDevice_"+this.i, false));
                this.i++;
                //(Somehow add CheckboxPreference to PreferenceFragment)
            }// end for loop
        }// end if(paired devices)
    }// end onCreate()
} // end PreferenceFragment
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Define stuff in onViewCreated() instead of in onCreate().

Search programmatically adding adding preferences to preference fragment.
Here's one example [How do I programmatically add EditTextPreferences to my PreferenceFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255383/how-do-i-programmatically-add-edittextpreferences-to-my-preferencefragment)